# Function passing each integer n and prints minimum number of bits required to store n as a signed integer

Tags: java, arrays, function, int, bit

I am having trouble finding a formula or finding the right conditionals to use when passing an array of integers and determining the minimum number of bits to store the signed integer. 
I have done the reverse to find the range of integers (min to max) given number of bits using equations:bits b: max = -2^(b-1)  min = 2^(b-1)-1 
Thanks for your help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] intAr = {2,15,16,100,1000,999999};

    printMinBits(intAr);
}

public static void printMinBits(int[] y)
{
    System.out.print("\n             min bits\nnumber       to store\n");
    for(int n = 0; n < y.length; n++)
    {    
        System.out.printf("%6d",y[n]);


        /*MISSING*/


        System.out.println("");
    }    
}
```

Output for min bits should be: 3,5,6,8,11,21 (in a table)

Comment: can you explain why the `min bits` for storing for example `2` is `3` when I think it should be `2` as it is `10` in `binary`?

Answer (score 1):

Integer class has builtin bit counting, and positioning methods.  Simple math to get the highest bit position, and therefor minimum bits needed:

```
private static int minBitsNeeded(int i) {
    return 1 + Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
}
```

So to fill in MISSING in your example:

```
public static void printMinBits(int[] y)
{
    System.out.print("\n             min bits\nnumber       to store\n");
    for(int n = 0; n < y.length; n++)
    {    
        System.out.printf("%6d",y[n]);

        System.out.printf( "%15d\n", minBitsNeeded(y[n]) );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used to find the minimum bits required to store a signed integer

```
public static int minBits(int n) {
    int b = 1;
    //If n is negative
    if(n < 0) {
        n *= -1;
    }
    while (n > 0) {
        n /=2;
        b++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need a function to get the bit count for a given `int`. You could do that with [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and something like

```
private static int getBitCount(int v) {
    String str = Integer.toBinaryString(v);
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == '0') {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1 + str.length() - count;
}
```

Then you could print your table with formatted io and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like

```
public static void printMinBits(int[] y) {
    System.out.println("Number to store\t\tMin bits");
    for (int v : y) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t\t\t%d%n", v, getBitCount(v));
    }
}
```

Which I executed with your provided `main` to get

```
Number to store     Min bits
2                   3
15                  5
16                  6
100                 8
1000                11
999999              21
```